# Highcharts styling, Legend & custom fonts

Tags: css, highcharts, custom-font

I have a problem with styling legend items in `Highcharts`, when applying a **Custom Font** to the legend items. Actually items are so close to each other and `itemMarginBottom` and `itemMarginTop` are not working.

Here is part of my `Highcharts` code:

```
legend: {
    enabled: true,
    y: 20,
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    margin: 30,
    width: 200,
    borderWidth: 0,
    itemMarginTop: 15,
    itemMarginBottom: 15,
    itemStyle: {
            color: '#000',
            fontFamily: 'MuseoS500'
    }
},
```

And here is the legend's screenshot:

[image]

**My Ugly Solution:**

I solved that like below, but sadly hard-coded:

```
// it is for the text's in the legend, I'll start from 0 and will
// increase by 10, so it's adding 10 pixels extra space to the next one
var z = 0;    

// this is for tiny-lines near the texts in legend, they starts from 14
// and increasing by 14 also ...
var p = 14;

// loop through <text> tags, which are texts in the lgened
$('.highcharts-legend > text').each( function (i) {

    // they have 'x' and 'y' attribute, I need to work on 'y' obviously
    y = parseInt($(this).attr('y'));

    // increasing 'y' value ...
    $(this).attr('y', y + z);

    // next element is <path>, the colorful lines ...
    $(this).next().attr('transform', 'translate(30,' + p + ')');

    // increasing the values, for the next item in the loop ...
    z = z + 10;
    p = p + 10 + 14;

});
```

I know that it's so stupid, but I couldn't solve that in any other ways, and I had to make them works somehow. I would be happy to hear your thoughts also ... :)

The new legends after the patch:

[image]

Comment: could it be a bug? I mean it looks weird ... :(

Comment: I am probably missing something but I do not see anything wrong with that screenshot.

Comment: @wergeld the margin top and bottom are set to 15, but you can't see there ... I've solved this one with JS, will post it here soon. :)

Comment: Yea, might have been better to show a border on the legend image that way would could see the difference in margins.

Comment: @wergeld I've updated the question with my own solution. The problem was the distance between items on the legend (like line-height), not margins of the legend frame. BTW, it's clear also without border, I guess. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Highchart documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.lineHeight) says that there is a property called `lineHeight` but Its deprecated since Highcharts 2.1

The post of official [Highcharts forum](http://www.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=8553&sid=1f4cd06d9516600891899ea77ed0b616) also confirms the same. So, Either you can hack source code to change the height according to your need or Try to correct item height with javascript after chart render.

Also, There is an attribute called `itemStyle` which allows to set CSS for legend item.

e.g. `paddingBottom: '10px'`

Check the example :

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/lineheight/

Comment: Or set `itemStyle.padding` to `5`.

Comment: Thanks Hardik, as you can see I've already fix that, however you're right and thanks for the information! :)