# How do I unbold title of Highcharts' legend?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

This is the API reference I found:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.title.style.fontWeight

Title's `fontWeight` is set to `bold` by default. I try setting it to `normal` or `lighter`. Neither produces compilation error but neither works.

```
legend: {
    title: {
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'lighter',
        }
    }
},
```

How do I change the `fontWeight`?

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        var scoreChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'scatter',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            legend: {
                title: {
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'lighter',
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'score',
                data: [[167.5, 59.0], [159.5, 49.2], [157.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
                    [170.0, 59.0], [159.1, 47.6],]
            },
            ]
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the legend fontWeight, by default, should not be set to bold

Comment: I'm willing to bet somewhere in your CSS you are setting `.highcharts-title` styling, which will ultimately override the ones you have set in the configuration

Comment: @Derek Thanks for your hint, but... there isn't. I can't even find a `bold` in my code.

Comment: We need a [mcve], or else we are just stumbling around in the dark.

Comment: @Wentao I guess you need to read some more what [mcve] really means, as that update doesn't execute and show the issue you describe.

Comment: @LGSon sorry, now it should suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To style `legend`, use `itemStyle`

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend

Stack snippet

```js
var scoreChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  legend: {
    itemStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'lighter'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'score',
    data: [
      [167.5, 59.0],
      [159.5, 49.2],
      [157.0, 63.0],
      [155.8, 53.6],
      [170.0, 59.0],
      [159.1, 47.6],
    ]
  }, ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well. I was looking for a way to unbold `score`, not title to the chart.

Comment: @Wentao Updated

Comment: And here is a SO-post I just found, with more stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777635/highcharts-styling-legend-custom-fonts